# Get the representation value of an enumeration type in Ada

Tags: enumeration, ada

I need to get the numeric value asociated with a value of an enumerated type in Ada. Not the position in the enumeration, but the value assigned with the "for TYPE use" clause to every value.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is currently no completely general solution.  Enumeration representation clauses seem to be designed to make this information difficult to obtain. (However Ada 2020 will add a solution; see the bottom of this answer for details.)

This:

```
function Rep is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Enum, Integer);
```

is likely to work in most cases, but there are some serious caveats: the representation values have to be within the range `Integer'First..Integer'Last`, and if the sizes of `Enum` and `Integer` don't match the result is actually implementation defined (but it works with GNAT).

As Simon Wright says, the RM recommends `Unchecked_Conversion`, but this is not a very satisfying solution, and determining a consistent target type is difficult.

As of the 2007 RM, the recommended level of support is:

> An implementation should support at least the internal codes in the
>   range System.Min_Int..System.Max_Int.

which means that converting to `Integer` is not always sufficient; a value could be less than `Integer'First`, or greater than `Integer'Last`.  And even if all the values are in that range, there's no really good way to determine a target type that's the same size as the enumeration type.  For example, this:

```
type Enum is (Ten, Twenty, Thirty);
for Enum use (10, 20, 30);
function Rep is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Enum, Integer);
```

produces this warning in GNAT:

```
warning: types for unchecked conversion have different sizes
```

But after the warning, Rep does return the expected values 10, 20, and 30.

The RM explicitly states that if the source and target sizes in an instance of Unchecked_Conversion don't match, and the result type is scalar, then

> the result of the function is implementation defined, and can have an 
>   invalid representation

So the fact that the above works for GNAT doesn't mean it's guaranteed to work everywhere.

For an implementation that *only* supports values in the range `System.Min_Int..System.Max_Int`, you can do something like this:

```
type Enum is (...);
for Enum use (...);
type Longest_Integer is range System.Min_Int .. System.Max_Int;
function Rep is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Enum, Longest_Integer);
```

and ignore the warning.  But compilers are *allowed* to accept values greater than System.Max_Int, as long as they're within the range of some integer type.  For example, GNAT rejects this, but another Ada compiler might accept it:

```
type Longest_Unsigned is mod System.Max_Binary_Modulus;
type Unsigned_Enum is (Zero, Huge);
for Unsigned_Enum use (0, Longest_Unsigned'Last);
```

and an Unchecked_Conversion from this to any signed integer type will not work.  And you still have the potential problem of implementation defined results if the sizes don't match.

Here's a generic solution that should work for any enumeration type *if* (a) the representation values are in the range `System.Min_Int..System.Max_Int`, and (b) if the implementation of `Unchecked_Conversion` is better behaved than the Ada standard requires it to be:

```
type Longest_Signed is range System.Min_Int .. System.Max_Int;

generic
    type Enum is (<>);
function Generic_Rep(E: Enum) return Longest_Signed;

function Generic_Rep(E: Enum) return Longest_Signed is
    function Rep is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Enum, Longest_Signed);
begin
    return Rep(E);
end Generic_Rep;
```

Given all this confusion, you might consider using some mechanism other than enumeration representation clauses to do whatever you're trying to do.

UPDATE:

GNAT has implementation-defined attributes `'Enum_Rep` and `'Enum_Val`. Ada 2020 is expected to adopt them.

http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-13-4.html#p10.1

Comment: Excellent Answer. Dont forget, you can also do the reverse (int to enum) and check the validity with 'valid !

Comment: Very nice answer. One note : the "different sizes" warning can be avoided if you create a new integer type, and specify the same Size attribute for both Enum and integer.
`type Unsigned_Byte is new natural range 0 .. 255;
for Unsigned_Byte'Size use 8; 
for Enum'Size use 8;`

Comment: or a type like `type short_int is mod 2**enum_type'size;`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, but what if Enum has negative values? `type Enum is (Minus_One, Zero, One); for Enum use (-1, 0, 1);`

Comment: you're right. And your comment applies to previous comment as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using GNAT, and don't mind going compiler-specific, that compiler provides the [Enum_Rep](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gnat_rm/Implementation-Defined-Attributes.html) attribute for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

[AARM 13.4](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-13-4.html) (para 11/1) recommends `Unchecked_Conversion` (to, probably, Integer).

Answer (score 2):

What I found to work in GNAT is for:

```
type MyEnum is (A, B, C);
```

I had to do:

```
EVal : MyEnum := B;
IVal : Integer := MyEnum'Enum_Rep(EVal);
```

Comment: `'Enum_Rep` and `'Enum_Val` are GNAT-specific, but they'll be adopted in the 2020 Ada standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the JVM or .NET compilers you could overlay the two; something like:

```
Value : Integer;
For Value'Address use ENUM_VAR'Address;
```

You're going to want to use the pragma that suppresses initialization, though I don't recall it at the moment.

IIRC, There's also the variant-record method, where you can overlay the fields exactly and use the record as a sort of view conversion.

Comment: `pragma Import (Value, Ada);`, I think.

Comment: If you're going to overlay a numeric item atop an enumeration, you should make sure the instance sizes are the same.

Answer (score 1):

*as i understand the quality and style guide, one should not take care of the inner representation values of enumerations at all. after a lot of research, i once decided to use the following construct:*

```
type enum_c is (clk_eq, clk_div_2, clk_div_16, clk_div_128, clk_div_1024);

type enum_c_values is array (enum_c) of natural; -- or any type you wish

cdiv_values : constant enum_c_values := (
   clk_eq         =>    1,
   clk_div_2      =>    2,
   clk_div_16     =>   16,
   clk_div_128    =>  128,
   clk_div_1024   => 1024 );

c : enum_c := clk_div_128;
...
put_line("c =" & c'img & " natural value associated w/ c =" & cdiv_values(c)'img);
```